# Что использовать вместо устаревшего @Required?

Tags: java, spring, required

Суть этой метки в том, что нельзя оставить поле/конструктор незаполненным. `@Autowired` не заменяет `@Required`, так как если оно найдет подходящий `bean`, то оно его подставит, что нам не нужно(нам нужно, чтобы это было указано вручную в конфигурации), хотя [некоторые думают, что `@Autowired` может заменить `@Required`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358835/11488556).

Comment: Может я не понял вопроса, но чем не нравится Autowired  + Qualifier ("beanName")?

Comment: @Дмитрий Это означает, что я задаю в коде название bean'а, который нужно подставить. Этот вариант подходит практически полностью - не заменяет он @ Required только в этом аспекте. Мы сужаем список до одного единственного bean'а конкретного имени. Это может помочь другому программисту. Думаю, это можно считать ответом.

Comment: честно говоря, ничего более подходящего мне в голову не приходит.